# jQuery RadioButtonList checked value returns "on"

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox, radio-button

I have a strange problem. I have a radio button list that when it is checked, it shows the div below that corresponds with the selected item. Above the radio button list is a check box list. The radio button click event works fine until you check a box from the above check box list. Once you check an item from the check box list above, it starts returning "on" rather than the selected radio button's value. Any idea?

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckAllTrucks(sendingcb) {
    $("#divTruckList :checkbox").prop("checked", $(sendingcb).prop("checked"));
}

function SetTimeframeInput(sendingrbl) {
    var value = $(sendingrbl + ":checked").val();

    $("#divTimeFrameControls .timeframectrls").each(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#div" + value).show();
}
```

HTML/ASP.NET Code:

```
<div class="form-field">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelectAllTrucks" runat="server" Text="Select All Trucks" onclick="CheckAllTrucks(this)" />
    <div id="divTruckList">
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblTrucks" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-field">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblTimeFrame" runat="server" onclick="SetTimeframeInput(this)">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Month" Value="month" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Quarter" Value="quarter" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="January-December" Value="jandec" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="July-June" Value="juljun" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <div id="divTimeFrameControls">
        <div id="divmonth" class="timeframectrls" style="display: none;">
            <!-- month fields -->
        </div>
        <div id="divquarter" class="timeframectrls" style="display: none;">
            <!-- quarter fields -->
        </div>
        <div id="divjandec" class="timeframectrls" style="display: none;">
            <!-- jandec fields -->
        </div>
        <div id="divjuljun" class="timeframectrls" style="display: none;">
            <!-- juljun fields -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT

I have found this only happens when one of the check boxes are checked. If you check and then uncheck, the value is still correct. It is only when a check box is checked does it set the value as "on".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still don't know what the problem was, but was able to fix it by referencing the ID of the radio button list directly. Like this:

```
function SetTimeframeInput() {
    var value = $("#rblTimeFrame input:checked").val();

    $("#divTimeFrameControls .timeframectrls").each(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#div" + value).show();
}
```

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `(this)` to functions try using `EventObject` which is passing by default on click :

```
function SetTimeframeInput(e) {
    var value = $(e.currentTarget).val();   

// value contains selected radio button`s value 

// continue your code here
```

}

I hope, this helps.

Comment: When I make the changes you mention, e is undefined.